# Do algebraic completion/topological completion of fields always terminate? If so, are they unique?

Tags: gn.general-topology, galois-theory, fields, p-adic-numbers

Take the field $\mathbb{Q}$, If we complete it topologically with respect to the Euclidean norm, we get $\mathbb{R}$, then if we complete it algebraically, we get $\mathbb{C}$.
On the other hand, the algebraic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and if we complete it with respect to the Euclidean norm now, we get $\mathbb{C}$.
So it indeed terminates and in fact the result is the same field/space.

Now, another example is the topological completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the p-adic norm, giving us $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the p-adic numbers, then the algebraic completion $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, and then once more with topological completion under p-adic norm, we get $\mathbb{C}_p$ which is the end.

Maybe this question can be better phrased in terms of ascending chains/homology but if anyone has any insight, that would be great.

Comment: I think the sentence *"On the other hand, the algebraic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and if we complete it with respect to the Euclidean norm now, we get $\mathbb{C}$"* is a bit confusing, because for a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, there is no unique extension of the norm (the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not invariant under the Galois action).

Comment: I think [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/247666/2362) of Laurent Moret-Bailly's at least addresses YCor's important objection (by observing that all extensions of the norm are conjugate) and gives some insight on the question. Does it make a difference if we consider valuations in an ordered abelian group versus norms valued in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: That's an interesting link, I'll look into it. I suppose working with norms valued in $\mathbb{R}$ is an easier starting place.

Comment: Isn't a completion of an algebraically closed field always algebraically closed?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is true for valued fields, but I'm not sure about general topological fields.

Comment: In fact, the problem does not make much sense if we don't restrict it to valued fields, because in general there is no preferred choice of a topology on the algebraic closure (not even up to isomorphism).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly ... how about his version for the non valued case.  Suppose $K$ is topologically complete and algebraically closed.  Let $F_0 \subset K$ be a subfield.  Let $F_1$ be the algebraic closure of $F_0$ in $K$.  Let $F_2$ be the topological closure of $F_1$ in $K$.  Is $F_2$ algebraically complete?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Interesting question. It reduces to this: let $F_2$ be a complete topological field having a dense subfield $F_1$ which is algebraically closed. Is $F_2$ algebraically closed?

Comment: Another general comment: the (topological) completion of a topological field is not always a field. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_2\times\mathbb{Q}_3$, which is therefore the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ for the induced topology. (This topology is generated by the 2-adic and 3-adic ones).

Comment: I will post a new question on this.

Comment: I posted a new question on this non-valued case https://mathoverflow.net/q/389220/454

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly When you say "$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_2\times\mathbb{Q}_3$", what kind of product is this?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais It is the product ring, with the product topology. Density is just (a special case of) the approximation theorem for independent valuations.